# DotNetZip Cancel extraction in Task

Tags: c#, task, dotnetzip

I have a method that executes a zip-extraction in a Task. Now I want the ability to Cancel the operation. But when I call the `Cancel()` method everything seems to stop immediately and the `while` runs forever:

```
public class OsiSourceZip
{
    private const string ZipPassword = "******";

    private bool _extractionDone;
    private bool _cancelExtraction;

    public async Task Extract(string sourceFile, string extractionDir)
    {
        Task extraction = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (ZipFile zipf = ZipFile.Read(sourceFile))
            {
                zipf.ExtractProgress += delegate(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs args)
                {
                    args.Cancel = _cancelExtraction;
                    RaiseExtractionProgressUpdate(args);
                };
                zipf.Password = ZipPassword;
                zipf.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
                zipf.ExtractExistingFile = ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
                zipf.ExtractAll(extractionDir);
            }
        });

        await extraction;
        _extractionDone = true;
        RaiseSourceInstallationCompleted();
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        _cancelExtraction = true;
        while (!_extractionDone)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I've set a break point on `args.Cancel = _cancelExtraction;` but the event is not fired anymore as soon as the `Cancel()` method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this. I basically got rid of my own `Cancel` Method and do it as the dotnetzip Framework wants it. In the progress event.

Let's say you want to cancel the operation when the `Form` gets closed. I capture the `FormClosing` Event, cancel the close procedure and remember the close request. The next time the progress event fires, I set the the `cancel` property in the event args and close the `Form` myself in the `completed` Event:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private bool _closeRequested;

    private void OnSourceInstallationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_closeRequested) { this.Close(); }            
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_closeRequested)
        {
            _closeRequested = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnExtractionProgressUpdate(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = _closeRequested;
    }
}
```

I think it's rather ugly but it works....